# Image URL help [CSS]

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, responsive

I would like to insert the image that I downloaded instead of using url, how could I do? I've this code:

```
 <div class="..." style="background-image:url=(http://www.example.com);"></div>
```

I would like to declare the image, like this: **assets/image/pic.jpg**

I've tried to does:

```
<div class="..." style="background-image:src="assets/image/pic.jpg"></div>
```

But doesn't work!

It's possible?

Comment: why equal sign?

Comment: you can still use the `url`, but instead of having the full URL of the image you can just use the path. `background-image: url('assets/image/pic.jpg');`. @JonathanWood is right, we need to know the path of the image and also the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be:

`<div class="..." style='background-image: url("assets/image/pic.jpg")'></div>`

Assuming that the path is correct, this should work. For more information please check out the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3c's documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp), no, you can't use any other than URL to specify `background-image`'s source

> `background-image: url|none|initial|inherit;`

You should remove the `=` symbol next to url in your `url=(http://www.example.com)` and it should work.

```html
<div class="background" style="height:400px; width:400px;background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats/')">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

in the css divert url and at the end of the instruction use the;
Try with

```
 <div class="..." style="background-image:url(assets/image/pic.jpg);"></div>
```